# how to make the string run?

Tags: r, escaping

```
> string="list.files(path=\"c:/\",pattern=\"ha.R\",recursive=TRUE)"
> string
[1] "list.files(path=\"c:/\",pattern=\"ha.R\",recursive=TRUE)"
> system.time(string)
   user  system elapsed 
      0       0       0
```

I want to  run `system.time(string)` as `system.time(list.files(path="c:/",pattern="ha.R",recursive=TRUE))`, how can i do ?

```
> system.time(list.files(path="c:/",pattern="ha.R",recursive=TRUE))
   user  system elapsed 
   1.56    3.48   47.03
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "assign a string" `list.files()` returns you a vector of filenames matching the conditions.